# How to move files into corresponding folders which have the same name?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, bittorrent, batch-rename

Example scenario:

I've multiple files ending with `.torrent` and I would like to move them into folders which has the same name.

For example given the following files:

```
abc.torrent
def.torrent
some files has spaces.torrent
or [special] (characters).torrent
or . (dots).torrent
xyz.torrent
```

I would like to move them into its corresponding folders (if exists) which has the exactly same name, for example:

- `abc.torrent` goes into `abc/`
- `def.torrent` goes into `def/`
- and so on

If the folder doesn't exist, file should stay untouched (as it may relate to incomplete download).

I believe BitTorrent doesn't have such options. If so, I would like to find some command line to achieve that.

Optionally I would like to specify the source folder of my files, and destination folder with expected directories.

Any ideas?

Comment: @terdon If directory doesn't exist, ignore the file and move on, since files could be related to incomplete downloads.

Comment: Oh well, I gave both options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Non-recursively:

  ```
  for t in *torrent; do [ -d "${t%.*}" ] && mv "$t" "${t%.*}"; done
  ```

  The `${var%pattern}` syntax removes the shortest match of `pattern` from the end of a variable. In this case, it simply removes the extension.
- Recursively (using `bash`):

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  for t in **/*torrent; do [ -d "${t%.*}" ] && mv "$t" "${t%.*}"; done
  ```

  The `globstar` option makes `**` match any files and 0 or more directories. Note that the above expects the target directory to be a subdirectory of the torrent file's parent directory. So, if a file is at `foo/bar/baz.torrent`, it will be moved to `foo/bar/baz/baz.torrent`.
- Non-recursively, creating the directory if absent:

  ```
  for t in *torrent; do mkdir -p "${t%.*}"; mv "$t" "${t%.*}"; done
  ```

  The `-p` option tells `mkdir` to print no error if the directory already exists and to create parent directories as needed. So, `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz` will also create the `foo` and `bar` directories if they don't exist.
- Recursively, creating the directory if absent:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  for t in **/*torrent; do mkdir -p "${t%.*}"; mv "$t" "${t%.*}"; done
  ```

Comment: For the 'creating directory if absent' part, I think you can use `$_` in the `mv` command as `mkdir` seems to update it regardless if the directory exists or not.

Comment: `**/*torrent` version generates paths, so `-d` check agains them (not name it-self), here is the version which using base names and move into `/foo` folder: `for t in **/*torrent; do [ -d /foo/"$(basename "${t%.*}")" ] && mv -v "$t" /foo/"$(basename "${t%.*}")/"; done`

Answer (score 3):

Since I couldn't find such option on OS X version of BitTorrent, I've wrote the following one-liner:

```
find . -name "*.torrent" -exec sh -c 'DST=$(find . -type d -name "$(basename "{}" .torrent)" -print -quit); [ -d "$DST" ] && mv -v "{}" "$DST/"' ';'
```

This will look for the `.torrent` files in the current directory (`.`) and find the folders (`DST`) with the same name recursively found in the same folder (`.`). To check for different directories, change the dots (`.`) to appropriate destinations. See complete script: [`mv_torrents.sh`](https://github.com/kenorb/binfiles/blob/master/mv_torrents.sh).